# ode15s command for coupled PDEs

Tags: pde, matlab

I am trying to solve the coupled PDE system given here-[Solve System of PDEs](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-system-of-pdes.html), using the method of lines and the ode15s command. Referring to variables $u1$ and $u2$ as $u$ and $v$ respectively, I have discretized the x domain as-
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \hspace{10pt} \forall i = 2,3,4...N-1$$ assuming there are N grid points. Discretizing the boundary conditions, I get-
$$u_1 = u_2 $$ $$v_1 = 0$$ $$v_{N-1} = v_N$$ $$u_N = 1$$ and the initial conditions would be- $$u = 1 \hspace{10pt} \forall \hspace{2pt} i=1,2,3...N$$ $$v = 0\hspace{10pt} \forall \hspace{2pt} i=1,2,3...N$$
I pack my solution vector in the form $[u \hspace{4pt}v]^T$ such that it looks like- $[u_2\hspace{4pt} u_3 \hspace{4pt}.... \hspace{4pt}u_{N-1},\hspace{4pt} v_2 \hspace{4pt} v_3 ....\hspace{4pt} v_{N-1}]$. So in total, I am solving for $2(N-2)$ variables and the values at the boundaries I can get manually. Here is the code I have written so far-

```
clc
clear all
tspan1 = 0:0.005:2;
xmesh1 = 0:0.005:1;

N = size(xmesh1);
N = N(1,2);

N2 = size(tspan1);
N2 = N2(1,2);

y01 = ones(N-2,1);
y02 = zeros(N-2,1);
y0 = [y01; y02];

[t,y] = ode15s(@pde2, tspan1, y0);
u1 = y(:,1:N-2);
u2 = y(:,N-1:2*(N-2));
v1 = u1(:,1);
v2 = ones(N2,1);
w1 = zeros(N2,1);
w2 = u2(:,N-2);
u1 = [v1 u1 v2];
u2 = [w1 u2 w2];

surf(xmesh1, tspan1, u2)
shading interp

function dydt = pde2(t, y)
    xmesh1 = 0:0.005:1;
    N = size(xmesh1);
    N = N(1,2);
    dx = 0.005;
    dydt = zeros(2*(N-2),1);
    dydt(1) = 0.024*(y(2)-y(1))/(dx*dx)-(exp(5.73*y(1))-exp(-11.47*y(N-1)));
    dydt(N-1) = 0.170*(y(N)-2*y(N-1)+0)/(dx*dx)+(exp(5.73*y(1))-exp(-11.47*y(N-1)));
    for i=2:N-2-1
        dydt(i) = 0.024*(y(i+1)-2*y(i)+y(i-1))/(dx*dx)-(exp(5.73*y(i))-exp(-11.47*y(i+N-2)));
        dydt(i+N-2) = 0.170*(y(N-1+i)-2*y(N-2+i)+y(N-3+i))/(dx*dx)+(exp(5.73*y(i))-exp(-11.47*y(i+N-2)));
    end
    dydt(N-2) = 0.024*(1-2*y(N-2)+y(N-3))/(dx*dx)-(exp(5.73*y(N-2))-exp(-11.47*y(2*(N-2)))); 
    dydt(2*(N-2)) = 0.170*(-y(2*(N-2))+y(2*(N-2)-1))/(dx*dx)+(exp(5.73*y(N-2))-exp(-11.47*y(2*(N-2))));
end
```

It's a bit inefficient, but I think it should get the job done. The problem is that I get a very different surface plot from the one given in the above link for $u1$ and $u2$ (or $u$ and $v$). For comparison, the plots of $u2$ have been attached.
[image]

This is the original plot for $u2$. This is what I get-
[image]

The shape looks a bit similar but the values are quite far off. I checked the equations in the pde2 function and they looked OK to me. The plot and values for $u1$ are also very different. Could someone point out the error in this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Does it have something to do with stiffness of the equations? It has been mentioned that the solution changes rapidly at small $t$. However I thought that using a stiff solver would circumvent this problem. I am able to solve the 1D heat equation without source term just fine with this approach but this particular problem eludes me.

Comment: This is more or less a "debug my code" post, which is unlikely to get much traction without more info provided. Try to remove components and see if you are getting correct results (compared to analytic solutions or MATLAB's built in PDE functions). For example, try one dependent variable, homogeneous boundary conditions, remove the nonlinearity, etc. There are lots of components that can go wrong in these types of codes, especially when it isn't written to be modular